# Elegant MVC code for optional surrounding tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

What would be more elegant code to accomplish the following:

```
foreach(var filter in Model.Filters)
{
  if(filter.Selected)
  {
    <div class="crumb crumb_selected" id="@filter.ID">
      @* much more html can be here *@
      @filter.Title
      <span class="counter">
        (@filter.Count)
      </span>
    </div>
  } else {
    <div class="crumb" id="@filter.ID">
      <a href="@Model.ClickUrl(Model.SelectedFilters, filter)">
      @* much more html can be here but similar code as above *@
        @filter.Title
        <span class="counter">
          (@filter.Count)
        </span>
      </a>
    </div>
  }
}
```

- the repeated html code for the div / span seems bad code
- also the css-class specification should be solved in the elegant version

Comment: You could just create partials and then your call would be `@Html.Partial("_filters", filter)` or something. Elegant is pretty subjective. I don't see much wrong with the above...sometimes code is ugly...sometimes it isn't

Comment: Your current solution is the most elegant.

Comment: I am still hoping for someone with an more elegant solution. I tried yesterday with using Razor templates and helpers but could not get it more elegant.

Comment: @Mikael Problem becomes more visible if the inner html part (title + span) becomes larger.

Comment: @Jacco In that case an inline helper is more elegant. See my answer below.

Comment: It might help if you explain what elegance means to you. It means a lot of things to a lot of people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@helper MyHelper(SomeDataType filter)
{
  @* much more html can be here *@
  @filter.Title
  <span class="counter">
    (@filter.Count)
  </span>
}

foreach(var filter in Model.Filters)
{
  if (filter.Selected)
  {
    <div class="crumb crumb_selected" id="@filter.ID">
      @MyHelper(filter)
    </div>
  } else {
    <div class="crumb" id="@filter.ID">
      <a href="@Model.ClickUrl(Model.SelectedFilters, filter)">
        @MyHelper(filter)
      </a>
    </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: Late response. Its still not as elegant as I had hoped for :-)

Comment: Maybe I should go for disabled <a href=""></a> :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(var filter in Model.Filters) 
{ 

    <div class="crumb @(filter.Selected? "crumb_selected":string.empty)" id="@filter.ID"> 
      @(filter.Selected? "<a href="@Model.ClickUrl(Model.SelectedFilters, filter)">" : string.empty)
      @filter.Title 
      <span class="counter"> 
        (@filter.Count) 
      </span> 
    </div> 
  }    
}
```

Essentially this just tests filter.Selected and is a more terse form of what you already have. I didn't test the syntax, just wrote it down off the top of my head so forgive me if it doesn't compile. I'm not sure this is more elegant, because I don't know what your definition of elegance is. I assumed you meant you more DRY.

Comment: It seems like the closing tag </a> is missing and I don't think HTML in a string is elegant.

Comment: why not? this is what the Html helper methods are doing, after all.

Comment: Its a route to consider. But won't the < > be rendered as &gt; &lt;? With Html.Raw added this would definately work, but I want to stay away from using Html.Raw in the elegant solution.